# on manipulating differentials when solving differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

Am I always allowed to treat differentials like dx as if it was just a small change in x and multiply/divide both sides of a differential equation by it? If not, what are the restrictions on the algebraic manipulations of those?

Comment: Depends who you ask tbh, it's a bit of an in-joke that physicists take a lot of liberties with doing this and it works out just fine

Comment: I'm reading Simmons differential equations textbook, and he gives me equations in which I'm expected to take dx as a common factor and divide dy by dx, which I'm not so comfortable doing. I just want to make sure that doing so never gets the wrong result

Comment: It works for sure for the first derivative when using total differentials. For the second derivative, you need a different notation for the second derivative $\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}\right)$. You can find out why in my paper "Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials." For partial derivatives, you need a better notation to separate out the meaning of the numerator depending on the denominator,such as $\frac{\partial_x y}{dx}$.  In all, the problems are notational, but if you don't use a notation compatible with such manipulations, it doesn't work.

Comment: @StephenDonovan It’s a pnemotenic rule that avoid some steps. We have to be careful. Probably, it was invented because it adds some intuition which is not harmful at all. Thanks.